# Use FontAwesome-Angular with an Angular npm Module for export

Tags: angular, typescript, module, font-awesome

I have an Angular 7 npm module (NOT a full app) that is meant to be imported into other Angular projects.  My module provides a header and footer that other apps can import.

I'm having trouble importing the fontAwesome module into my module.

Here is my ncui.module.ts file (i do not have an app.module.ts file since this isn't an app):

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';

import { NcuiFooterComponent } from './ncui-footer.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FontAwesomeModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    NcuiFooterComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    NcuiFooterComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ]
})
export class NcuiModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: NcuiModule,
      providers: [
        ...
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

And my footer.component.ts file (abbreviated of course):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { faQuestionCircle } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@Component({
  selector: 'ncui-footer',
  templateUrl: './ncui-footer.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    './css/global-main.scss'
  ]
})
export class NcuiFooterComponent implements OnInit {
  faQuestionCircle = faQuestionCircle;

  constructor(private ncuiAddressService: NcuiAddressService) {}
}
```

And my footer.component.html file (the relevant piece only):

```
<div>
  <fa-icon [icon]="faQuestionCircle"></fa-icon>
</div>
```

When i run my tests, I get this error:

```
Can't bind to 'icon' since it isn't a known property of 'fa-icon'.
        1. If 'fa-icon' is an Angular component and it has 'icon' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
        2. If 'fa-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

Any ideas what I need to do to import FontAwesome here?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was that i had not imported it into the spec.ts file.  Here was the fix:

```
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { NcuiFooterComponent } from './ncui-footer.component';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';

describe('NcuiFooterComponent', () => {
  let component: NcuiFooterComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<NcuiFooterComponent>;
  let de: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(async(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [NcuiFooterComponent],
    imports: [
      FontAwesomeModule
    ]
  }).compileComponents()));

  ...

});
```